# How to specify additional identifers while using 'load.instruments' in 'FinancialInstrument' package

Tags: r

I want to use `load.instruments` from `FinancialInstrument` package, to create multiple instruments from meta data from a csv file.

My csv file called `roots_test.csv` looks like

```
primary_id,description,type,exchange,currency,multiplier,initialmargin,identifiers
AD,Australian Dollar-CME(Floor+Electronic Combined),future,GLOBEX,USD,100000.00,5400,AUD
```

Now if I call `load.instruments` it loads data properly and I can get instrument by using both `AD` and `AUD`.

**However say now I want to specify another identifier for same instrument say `AD2` , how to do that?**

```
> load.instruments(file = 'roots_test.csv', default_type="future")
Warning messages:
1: In read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote,  :
  incomplete final line found by readTableHeader on 'roots_test.csv'
2: In future(primary_id = "AD", description = "Australian Dollar-CME(Floor+Electronic Combined)",  :
  underlying_id should only be NULL for cash-settled futures
3: In instrument(primary_id = primary_id, currency = currency, multiplier = multiplier,  :
  identifiersAUDdo not appear to be a named list

> getInstrument("AD")
primary_id   :"AD"
currency     :"USD"
multiplier   :1e+05
tick_size    : NULL
identifiers  :List of 1
 ..$ :"AUD"
type         :"future"
description  :"Australian Dollar-CME(Floor+Electronic Combined)"
exchange     :"GLOBEX"
initialmargin:5400
underlying_id: NULL

> getInstrument("AUD")
primary_id   :"AD"
currency     :"USD"
multiplier   :1e+05
tick_size    : NULL
identifiers  :List of 1
 ..$ :"AUD"
type         :"future"
description  :"Australian Dollar-CME(Floor+Electronic Combined)"
exchange     :"GLOBEX"
initialmargin:5400
underlying_id: NULL
```

Comment: Please avoid creating two new tags for one question, thanks!